# heroku is rejecting the push for the application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

```
     list of known hosts.
Counting objects: 67, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (51/51), done.
Writing objects: 100% (67/67), 25.61 KiB, done.
Total 67 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.1.rc
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/
-binstubs bin/
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
       Installing rake (0.9.2.2)
       Installing multi_json (1.0.4)
       Installing activesupport (3.1.1)
       Installing builder (3.0.0)
       Installing i18n (0.6.0)
       Installing activemodel (3.1.1)
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing rack (1.3.5)
       Installing rack-cache (1.1)
       Installing rack-mount (0.8.3)
       Installing rack-test (0.6.1)
       Installing hike (1.2.1)
       Installing tilt (1.3.3)
       Installing sprockets (2.0.3)
       Installing actionpack (3.1.1)
       Installing mime-types (1.17.2)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
       Installing treetop (1.4.10)
       Installing mail (2.3.0)
       Installing actionmailer (3.1.1)
       Installing arel (2.2.1)
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.31)
       Installing activerecord (3.1.1)
       Installing activeresource (3.1.1)
       Using bundler (1.1.rc)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.1.3)
       Installing execjs (1.2.11)
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2)
       Installing json (1.6.3) with native extensions
       Installing rdoc (3.11)
       Installing thor (0.14.6)
       Installing railties (3.1.1)
       Installing coffee-rails (3.1.1)
       Installing jquery-rails (1.0.19)
       Installing rails (3.1.1)
       Installing sass (3.1.11)
       Installing sass-rails (3.1.5)
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.5) with native extensions Unfortunately,
error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracke
ps://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Thanks!
       /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `rescue in
n build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::
r::ExtensionBuildError)
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library searc
the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for
       details.  You may need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
       --enable-local
       --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendo
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
sqlite3-1.3.5/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `bloc
ld_extensions'
       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `each
       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `buil
ions'
       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:198:in `inst
       from /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundl
c/lib/bundler/source.rb:90:in `block in install'
       from /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundl
c/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:78:in `preserve_paths'
       from /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundl
c/lib/bundler/source.rb:89:in `install'
       from /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundl
c/lib/bundler/installer.rb:73:in `block in install_gem_from_spec'
       from /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundl
c/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:93:in `with_build_args'
       from /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundl
c/lib/bundler/installer.rb:72:in `install_gem_from_spec'
       from /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundl
c/lib/bundler/installer.rb:56:in `block in run'
       from /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundl
c/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `run'
       from /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundl
c/lib/bundler/installer.rb:12:in `install'
       from /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundl
c/lib/bundler/cli.rb:219:in `install'
       from /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundl
c/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
       from /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundl
c/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
       from /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundl
c/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
       from /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundl
c/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
       from /tmp/build_2v67f08duz36y/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundl
c/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
       from vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
       from vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:deep-summer-6670.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:deep-summer-6670.git'
```

Any ideas why?

## Edit 1

Here is my gemfile

```
    # SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'pg'
development:
  adapter: pg
  encoding: utf8
  database: ror_blog
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: cPEProot
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock


# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: move gem sqlite to development group

Comment: I didnt get you, can you be specific please?

Comment: `Here is my gemfile`
Wait... what? It's database.yml, not Gemfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the sqlite3 gem to the development group so it won't get installed on Heroku.

Open your `Gemfile`, locate the gem and move it to the group like so:

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```